# rails form post do not redirect to intended page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now I tried to get the input from form tag using the post method in index.erb

```
<form action="/home/login" method="post">
  <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
  <input type="text" name="uid">
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <input type="submit" value="login">
</form>
```

in the routes.rb I have

```
  post 'home/login'
```

and for the homecontroller

```
  def login
    @uid=params[:uid]
    @password=params[:password]
  end
```

I have login.erb

```
<h1> Result </h1>

<%=@uid %>
<%=@password %>
```

I am new to rails. 
In mye knowledge, as form send the two inputs using action="/home/login", then rails look for the url in routes.rb which is post 'home/login'. 
Then, routes.rb connects to controller which would be homecontroller > def login. 
Then, def login does the logic and redirect to login.erb

[image]

so, If I put the id and password 123, I want

[image]

form redirect me to login.erb successfully when I use the get method.
However, when I use post method in form tag, the actual result is

[image]

It does send inputs to controller and receive the data to login.erb, yet I do not know why it is not redirected to login.erb (like above when I use get method), it only shows up on index.erb

I am not sure why it works like ajax. I have used the spring and spring boot before, but what is difference using the post method for rails.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by change the every .erb file to .html.erb

Answer (score 2):

You are new to rails so let me explain to you how things work.Lets say you want to post a form at "localhost/form".
First thing you want to do is to write to routes.rb:
post "/form" ,to: "controller_name#action_name"
After you need to manage the form's data submitted (in the above action) through params[:] (which you already do).
Now this is the important part. You need to declare in your action what will happen after.
You can use:
**redirect_to** "another_page" (if i understand correctly this is what you want) or
**render** partial.
If you want to update something in the page where the form is you can use AJAX through jquery.I hope that helps.Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Yeah, I already used redirect_to "another_page" but, another page is showing up in the index.erb like the very bottom screenshot

Comment: So can you please explain what you want to happen after post submit?

Comment: So, my question is after make post submittion, is it page suppose to be redirected to login.erb? I am not understand why it stays at same page. While get submit actually redirect to login.erb

Comment: When using get request , rails renders the view that has the same name with the controller's action. When using post request you must add code to your action to tell rails what you want to view.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So, when I use redirect_to "/home/about" after post submit, why page is not redirected to 'home/about'?  I put get 'home/about' in routes.rb and def about in home controller. But, it only pops up at the index.erb page

Comment: I believe that something is wrong with your routing. You probably don't call the right actions when an event is triggered. I would suggest using your command line when you submit a form and see what action of your controller is called(using the command line to watch your program's flow is essential). When you check that the right action is called you can add code: redirect_to etc based on what you want to happen. I hope that helps.

Comment: when I check the console, it says started POST "/home/login" and rendering home/about.erb and not sure why it does not change the page